# How to call a web api via ajax over SSL from a local html file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ssl, cors

I have a local html file in may desktop accessing a web api (JAX-RS) that responds with some JSON data. I enabled CORS and everything works fine, but only without SSL. How can I do to make it work with SSL? I use a self-signed certificate and can call this web api from a WPF application, but from a JavaScript application (standalone html file), when Chrome sends the OPTIONS pre-flight before the POST, the request seems not to even reach the server. I also tried to import the self-signed certificate in the browser, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The preflight request is not allowed to include an entity body or credentials. If you are using preflighted requests then you cannot use two way SSL.

The solution is to change the server to make the certificate optional. I've only done this using Apache HTTP server or Tomcat but I assume other servers are also capable of this.

In apache the setting should be changed to

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
```

and in Tomcat the SSL settings should be changed to

```
clientAuth="want"
```

Without this change only CORS simple requests will work.